# aws ec2 ubuntu GUI fail to lunch due to Error setting MTRR

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu-14.04, gnome-3

I have wasted almost two days searching the web to find an answer to this problem.

I launched an AWS EC2 instance with Latest Ubuntu server.

I installed latest GNOME.

Now, I would like just to lunch it.

So I entered "sudo startx" but it fails due to:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-42-220:/$ sudo startx


X.Org X Server 1.15.1
Release Date: 2014-04-13
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-76-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux ip-172-31-42-220 3.13.0-48-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 12 11:16:15 UTC 2015 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-48-generic root=UUID=c70a26ec-1dda-455c-acfd-792015b2bb6f ro console=tty1 console=ttyS0
Build Date: 12 February 2015  02:49:29PM
xorg-server 2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2.7 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support)
Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.1.log", Time: Thu Apr 23 13:50:28 2015
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
Initializing built-in extension XTEST
Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
Initializing built-in extension SYNC
Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
Initializing built-in extension RENDER
Initializing built-in extension RANDR
Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
Initializing built-in extension RECORD
Initializing built-in extension DPMS
Initializing built-in extension Present
Initializing built-in extension DRI3
Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
Initializing built-in extension XVideo
Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
Initializing built-in extension SELinux
Initializing built-in extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DGA
Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DRI
Initializing built-in extension DRI2
Loading extension GLX
error setting MTRR (base = 0xf0000000, size = 0x00100000, type = 1) Invalid argument (22)
```

I read more than a dozens of link

Can someone please assist here?

Thanks in advance.